# Slow ethernet Kubuntu 18:04

Tags: kubuntu, ethernet

I have a laptop with realtek network adaptors.
RTL8821AE 802.11ac
RTL8111/8168/8411
As the wifi does not work well at all on Kubuntu I bought a couple of powerline adaptors so I could use the ethernet connection. I have been using this set up for quite some time but recently I have been getting very slow internet connections.
First I thought it was my isp but realised my phone was connecting fine as was another laptop on wireless. Then I though the powerline adaptors but a quick test shows I get good speed using them with my laptop on Windows 10 (70mbs up on a broadband speed test and about 5 down)
On Kubuntu I am getting under 5 down and 5 up. Plugging direct to the router gives the same result so the problem is my ethernet connection on the laptop, under Linux (4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 16:00:05 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)
Until a week or two ago everything worked fine so any idea what might be the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Doh, turns out at some stage (an update maybe) network manager has stopped using autonegotiate for speed and picked 100Mbit/s - yes although less then the possible 1Gbit/s it is still more than 70Mbit/s I get in Windows so should not be a problem and so I should still get more than 5Mbit/s BUT setting to autonegotiate, removing and replacing the ethernet cable and suddenly, after a couple of weeks slow connection, I am seeing 70Mbit/s again.
So problem solved and something to look out for if another update or something breaks internet speed again.

Comment: super! same problem in Kubuntu 19.10 with kde neon. you just made my day!